# ifstream::read not working?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am trying to read from a `.csv` file.  There are two functions below, one for writing and one for reading.

The file contains a simple table:

```
date,first,second
1     a      one
2     b      two
3     c      three
4     c      four
```

For some reason, the statement `while(file_stream.read(&c,1));` does not read anything.  It stops at the first character and I'm dumbfounded as to why.  Any clues?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

std::string filename;
std::string line_string;
ifstream file_stream;
stringstream ss;
vector< vector<string> > vec;
char c;

void read_file()
{
    filename = "test.csv";

    cout << filename << endl;

    file_stream.open(filename.c_str(),ios::out|ios::binary);
    if(file_stream.fail())
    {
        cout << "File didn't open" << endl;
        return;
    }

    if(file_stream.is_open())
        cout << "file opened" << endl;

    while(file_stream.read(&c,1));  // this isn't working
    {
        cout <<"char c is: " <<  c;
        ss << noskipws << c;
    }
    file_stream.close();
    cout << "string is: " << ss.str() << endl;

    //get each line
    int counter = 0;
    vector<string> invec;

    while(getline(ss,line_string,'\n'))
    {
        string header_string;
        stringstream header_stream;

        header_stream << line_string;

        while(getline(header_stream, header_string,','))
        {
            invec.push_back(header_string);
        }
        invec.push_back(header_string);

        vec.push_back(invec);
        invec.clear();
        counter++;
    }
}

void test_output()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size();i++)
    {
        for(int in = 0; in < vec[0].size(); in++)
            cout << vec[i][in] << "   ";

        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    read_file();
    test_output();
}
```

Comment: change what to std::fstream::in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look *very very carefully* at the line that is not working:

```
while(file_stream.read(&c,1));  // this isn't working
{
    cout <<"char c is: " <<  c;
    ss << noskipws << c;
}
```

The `;` character at the end of the `while` statement does NOT belong!  You are running a **no-body loop** that does not terminate until `read()` fails, and THEN your code enters the bracketed block to output the *last* character that was successfully read (if any).

You need to remove that erroneous `;` character:

```
while(file_stream.read(&c,1))  // this works
{
    cout <<"char c is: " <<  c;
    ss << noskipws << c;
}
```

---

Now, the real question is - why are you reading the input file character-by-character into a `std::stringstream` in the first place?  You can use `std::getline()` with the input `std::ifstream` directly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > vec;

void read_file()
{
    std::string filename = "test.csv";

    std::cout << filename << std::endl;

    std::ifstream file_stream;
    file_stream.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
    if (!file_stream)
    {
        std::cout << "File didn't open" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "file opened" << std::endl;

    //get each line
    std::vector<std::string> invec;
    std::string line;
    int counter = 0;

    if (std::getline(file_stream, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);    
        while (std::getline(iss, line, ','))
            invec.push_back(line);    
        vec.push_back(invec);
        invec.clear();
        ++counter;

        while (std::getline(file_stream, line))
        {
            iss.str(line);
            while (iss >> line)
                invec.push_back(line);    
            vec.push_back(invec);
            invec.clear();
            ++counter;
        }
    }
}

void test_output()
{
    if (!vec.empty())
    {
        for(int in = 0; in < vec[0].size(); ++in)
            std::cout << vec[0][in] << ",";

        std::cout << std::endl;

        for(int i = 1; i < vec.size(); ++i)
        {
            for(int in = 0; in < vec[i].size(); ++in)
                std::cout << vec[i][in] << "   ";

            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    read_file();
    test_output();
}
```

Comment: haha.. Thanks for that.. It's taken hours and it was a stupid typo in the end.   Thanks for bringing this to my attention.  My own silly mistake.